# Two routes for the same action Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that lists all the subaccounts under a main account. However when I click the subaccount, instead of going to do `accounts/1/subaccounts/1` I want it to go to `subaccounts/1`. When I use the for_each statement I get the following error. How can I click on a nested route and have it go to just `subaccounts/1` instead of `accounts/1/subaccounts/1`?

[image]

```
<% @subaccounts.each do |sa| %>
    <%= link_to "#{sa.name}", subaccount_path(sa) %>
<% end %>
```

### Routes.rb

```
resources :subaccounts

resources :accounts do
  resources :subaccounts
end
```

### Subaccounts controller

```
before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :new, :create]
before_action :set_subaccount, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def show
end


private
    def set_account
      @account ||= Account.find(params[:account_id])
    end

    def set_subaccount
      @subaccount ||= @account.subaccounts.find(params[:id])
    end

    def subaccount_params
      params.require(:subaccount).permit(:name, :state)
    end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to same controller action for 2 different routes. You can fix it by either adding another controller for nested route

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :subaccounts, controller: 'accounts_subaccounts'
end
```

Or handle exception and check for `@account` (least preferred way / bad practice)

```
@account ||= Account.find(params[:account_id]) rescue nil
```

With handling with rescue you need to handle @account everywhere.
You can also trigger set_account method when `params[:account_id].present?` which will also work for you.

Comment: `rescue nil` is a bad practice. `@account ||= Account.find_by(id: params[:account_id])`